# Наследуемый класс должен иметь приватный конструктор

Tags: c#

Написал реализацию базового синглтона, от которого будут наследоваться конкретные классы. Вот код:

```
public class InputSettings : SingletonObject<InputSettings>
{
    private InputSettings()
    {
    }
}

public abstract class SingletonObject<T> where T : SingletonObject<T>
{
    private static readonly Lazy<T> instance;

    public static T GetInstance()
    {
        return instance.Value;
    }

    static SingletonObject()
    {
        instance = new Lazy<T>(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
                    return (T)constructor.Invoke(null);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Сейчас для каждого наследуемого класса необязательно создавать приватный конструктор, что нарушает принцип синглтона.
Как сделать так, что наследуемый класс обязательно должен был реализовывать приватный конструктор?

Comment: Вроде как невозможно заставить потомков иметь определённый уровень доступа. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12799459/5045688

Comment: `where T : SingletonObject<T>` - Вы точно это хотели написать?

Comment: where T : SingletonObject<T> Да. это нужно убрать.

Comment: оч странная реализация синглтона. 1) зачем вам класс `InputSettings` наследовать от синглтона? Что вам мешает сделать просто так `SingletonObject<InputSettings>.GetInstance();` без наследований?

Comment: 2) вы ловите исключение только для того, чтобы снова его запустить? `catch (Exception e)`

Comment: 3) Для чего вообще такой сингтон создавать? Вы не используете DI? У вас все сингтоны инициализируются в конструкторе? А если для инициализации синглтона в БД надо будет залезть, вы что будете делать?